# How to set Rating Bar using Array List

Tags: android, arrays, listview

Im try to set value of Rating Bar using Array List,  im set the value of rating to Float, but i don't know how to set the value and show it into the Rating Bar, and im use listview to show the data. please help me to solve this problem

this is my Artikel Activity, im set the ratingbar into float

package com.example.latihanlist;

```
public class Artikel {
    private int imageId;
    private float ratingId;
    private String title;
    private String timestamp;
    private String descriptions;

    public Artikel(int imageId, String title, String timestamp, String
            descriptions, float ratingId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.title = title;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.descriptions = descriptions;
        this.ratingId = ratingId;
    }
    public int getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }

    public float getRatingId() {
        return ratingId;
    }

    public void setImageId(int imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }
    public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
    public String getDescriptions() {
        return descriptions;
    }
    public void setDescriptions(String descriptions) {
        this.descriptions = descriptions;
    }
}
```

here my MainActivity, im set the value for rating 2.0

```
package com.example.latihanlist;

        import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewStub;
        import android.widget.AdapterView;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.RatingBar;
        import android.widget.Toast;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewStub stubList;
    private ListView listview;
    private ListViewArrayAdapter listViewArrayAdapter;
    private List<Artikel> artikelList;

    private List<Artikel> getArtikelList() {
        artikelList= new ArrayList<>();
        artikelList.add(new Artikel(R.drawable.mob,"Title 1","1 hours ago","Descriptions of text 1", "2.0"));
        artikelList.add(new Artikel(R.drawable.mob,"Title 2","1 hours ago","Descriptions of text 2", "2.0"));
        artikelList.add(new Artikel(R.drawable.mob,"Title 3","1 hours ago","Descriptions of text 3", "2.0"));
        artikelList.add(new Artikel(R.drawable.mob,"Title 4","1 hours ago","Descriptions of text 4", "2.0"));
        artikelList.add(new Artikel(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,"Title 5","1 hours ago","Descriptions of text 5", "2.0"));
        return artikelList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        stubList=(ViewStub) findViewById(R.id.stublist);
        stubList.inflate();
        listview=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        stubList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        getArtikelList();
        listViewArrayAdapter=new ListViewArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.list_item,artikelList);
        listview.setAdapter(listViewArrayAdapter);


        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                   //     artikelList.get(position).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("dataTitle", artikelList.get(position).getTitle().toString());
                bundle.putInt("dataImg", artikelList.get(position).getImageId());
                bundle.putString("dataDesc", artikelList.get(position).getDescriptions().toString());

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailBerita.class);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        Button mBtn_login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mBtn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuApkAndroid.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

this is my list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/mob"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTitle"
        android:text="Title of the Text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTime"
        android:layout_below="@id/textTitle"
        android:text="1 hours ago"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="9dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textDesc"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTime"
        android:text="This is descriptions of the title of text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="10dp"/>

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1.0"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hi. Could you please post your customeArrayAdapter code here?

Answer (score 0):

Let we discuss first behaviour of RatingBar.

Official Document say:

> When using a RatingBar that supports user interaction, placing widgets
>   to the left or right of the RatingBar is discouraged.
>
> The number of stars set (via setNumStars(int) or in an XML layout)
>   will be shown when the layout width is set to wrap content (if another
>   layout width is set, the results may be unpredictable).

Meaning RatingBar will not work as expected if you put any view to the left or right of RatingBar.

It will not work also if you set RatingBar width other than wrap_content.

"But I need views left or right or both to the RatingBar. Is it possible to do?"

Yes!!!

"How??"

Put RatingBar alone inside a Layout.Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cell1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cell2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:stepSize="1.0"
        />
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

For more detail check official [RatingBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar).

Now,Come to the point. Where is the solution for me??.

Your all the code is fine except rating parameter in Artikel Object.That must be float as per your definition of class.I think compiler will give you that error.

Since your are using RelativeLayout so i think you will not have issue of left-right too.

You need to set the ArrayAdapter properly.

Have a look on following:

```
public class ListViewArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Artikel> {
    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<Artikel> mArtikels;
    public ListViewArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull ArrayList<Artikel> artikels) {
        super(context, 0, artikels);
        mContext = context;
        mArtikels = artikels;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItem = convertView;
        if (listItem ==null){
            listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.artikel_list_item,parent,false);
        }
        Artikel artikel = mArtikels.get(position);

        ImageView imageView = listItem.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView title = listItem.findViewById(R.id.textTitle);
        TextView time = listItem.findViewById(R.id.textTime);
        TextView disc = listItem.findViewById(R.id.textDesc);
        RatingBar ratingBar = listItem.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);

        imageView.setImageResource(artikel.getImageId());
        title.setText(artikel.getTitle());
        time.setText(artikel.getTimestamp());
        disc.setText(artikel.getDescriptions());

        ratingBar.setRating(artikel.getRatingId());

        return listItem;
    }
}
```

Hope It will help. [Full Source code is here](https://github.com/codewithvikas/Exploring-Android/tree/exploring-listview-with-ratingbar)

Please Up Vote if it works. Happy coding.

Thanks